# Rails and database: find entry if exists else create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table in database that has the following columns:

> 1. id
> 2. package1_name
> 3. package2_name

And I have two `file_field`s in my `_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(@submission, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
 <%= f.fields_for :uploads do |upload| %>
  <%= upload.file_field :package1 %>
  <%= upload.file_field :package2 %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Every time I click the submit button it will create two separate entries in the database.

Is there a way to change the behavior of `create` so that it will find the database entry if exist else create a new entry?

I have tried this but it doesnt work:

```
def create
    @submission = Submission.find_or_create_by_id(params[:submission])
    ...
end
```

Comment: Why will each click of submit create two entries right now? Shouldn't it simply be creating one entry with the two attributes `:package1` and `:package2`?

Comment: @abhir, sorry for my bad english, what I meant is I click the submit once and it will creates two entries in the db.

Comment: Why do you have `fields_for :uploads`? You said they're columns on your instance, not associations.

Comment: @mathieugagne, I have a nested model where `submission` has many `upload`

Answer (score 1):

This will only create the submission if a record with the id in params[:submission][:id] doesn't exist.

```
def create
   @submission = Submission.where(:id => params[:submission][:id]).first_or_create(params[:submission])
end
```

However, I am with abhir that it doesn't seem right that the form calls the create method twice. It seems weird that you need to do this. Anyway, in case that behavior is correct, I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Actually I am also wondering why it would call `create` method twice each time when I submit it, I am using some file upload plugins to handle the file upload so maybe they somehow change the way that the applications inserts